# In PowerShell how can we download a folder from a password protected website

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

Used links method to get the webpage content to download the specific folder but the webpage content doesn't contains the details about the folder then how can we download the folder from the website

Used href links method